# Adding CSS to extra tpl file

Tags: css, custom-templates

I've added CSS to a Summary.extra.tpl file to change reports. But the CSS does not apply.

Adding the CSS by itself crashes the report (character encoding issue) so adding the {literal} tag is what I have.

```
{literal}
#s2id_groups {display:none;}
{/literal}
```

I am trying to remove the add contacts to group dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do it with css but I might use jquery instead:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
CRM.$(function($) {
  $('#s2id_groups').hide();
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

The problem with css might also be that you don't have a `<style type="text/css">` tag around your css?

Comment: Thanks Demerit. Adding the style tag was needed. I haven't done much with these tpl files so great to know what is needed.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 solutions on how to achieve this

1 - Adding Javascript in tpl file as mentioned by Demerit

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  CRM.$(function($) {
    $('.crm-report-form-block select[name="groups"]').closest('td').hide();
  });
</script>
{/literal}
```

2 - Adding a code using buildForm hook in an extension

```
function membershipapproval_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  // unset from all reports
  // Change if condition to $formName == 'CRM_Report_Form_Event/Summary'
  // if want to hide on specific event
  if (get_parent_class($form) == 'CRM_Report_Form') {
    $groupsElementIndex = CRM_Utils_Array::value('groups', $form->_elementIndex);
    if ($groupsElementIndex) {
      unset($form->_elements[$groupsElementIndex]);
    }
  }
}
```

3 - Adding CSS in tpl file as

```
{literal}
<style type="text/css">
 #s2id_groups {
  display:none;
 }
</style>
{/literal}
```

HTH

Pradeep